# convert python to sql

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I am trying to use a python code in my django app for which I need to convert my python code in SQL.

Here is the python code:

```
dfc = pd.merge(man, tra, on=['From', 'To', 'T_Type', 'T_Length', 'T_Weight'], how='inner')
dfc.drop(['From', 'To', 'M_Type', 'T_Weight', 'T_Length', 'Loading_Time', 'T_Type'], axis = 1,inplace=True)
dfc = dfc[dfc['#Trucks_y'] >= dfc['#Trucks_x']].drop(['#Trucks_y', '#Trucks_x'], axis=1)
```

The columns of **man** are:

```
Load_ID
M_ID
From
To
M_Type
T_Type
T_Length
T_Weight
#Trucks
Loading_Time
```

columns of **tra**:

```
T_ID
From
To
T_Type
T_Length
T_Weight
#Trucks
Price
T_rating
```

What is the SQL equivalent of the above python code such that i get these columns(based on the above conditions) in my **dfc**:

```
Load_ID
M_ID
T_ID
Price
T_rating
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy, Use the code below:

```
>>> dfc.query()
>>> 'SELECT ..... WHERE ....'
```

It will appear. Make sure to run the code in Django Shell

Comment: using the above it gives me output as `[(1, 'load', '0', '0', 5, 'Fragile', '0', 0, 2, 1, 15, 'test', '0', '0', 5, '0', 0, 1, 1), (1, 'load', '0', '0', 5, 'Fragile', '0', 0, 2, 1, 1, 'truck', '0', '0', 5, '0', 0, 1, 1)]`  where **1, 'load', '0', '0', 5, 'Fragile', '0', 0, 2, 1** will be repeated multiple times. Can it give me a table which doesn't repeat it ?

Comment: try dfc.object.all().query() at last line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this should work for you. Note that `From`, `To` etc are SQL keywords, so you may need to use different column names or properly quote (`""`) them.

```
SELECT
    t1.load_id,
    t1.m_id,
    t2.t_id,
    t2.price,
    t2.t_rating
FROM
    man t1
JOIN tra t2 ON
    t1."From" = t2."From"
    AND t1."to" = t2."to"
    AND t1.t_type = t2.t_type
    AND t1.t_length = t2.t_length
    AND t1.t_weight = t2.t1.t_weight
    AND t2."#trucks" >= t1."#trucks";
```